# Create column if it doesn't exist using Liquibase

Tags: sql, oracle, comments, liquibase, oracle19c

In Liquibase SQL syntax, is it possible to check if a column doesn't already exist?
I have seen that theres a `columnExists` precondition, but couldn't find the opposite of it.

```sql
--changeset me:1 runAlways:false runOnChange:false failOnError:true
--precondition-column-exists tableName:my_table columnName:my_col
INSERT COLUMN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something as below:

```
--changeset me:1 runAlways:false runOnChange:false failOnError:true
--precondition-sql-check expectedResult:0 SELECT COUNT(*) from information_schema.columns where column_name='COL' and table_name='TABLE'
INSERT COLUMN QUERY HERE
```

The above precondition will check if there exists column `COL` in table `TABLE`, if the count returned is 0 ( which means the column doesn't exists) then the INSERT COLUMN query will be executed.

At the moment only the "SQL check" precondition is supported in "formatted SQL" changelogs. Have a look at [liquibase docs](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/basic/sql-format.html).

> Preconditions can be specified for each changeset. Currently, only the
> SQL check precondition is supported.
>
> ````
> --preconditions onFail:HALT onError:HALT
> --precondition-sql-check expectedResult:0 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table ```
> ````